# Why I can't set on the Debian 64 bit on the Virtual Box

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64bit

I have installed the Virtual Box, and I would like to make a Debian virtual machine but I can't do this because my Virtual Box don't allow me to choose Debian x64. My computer and the .iso file  are x64 too, that's why I don't understand why I can't choose it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system?

Comment: The VirtualBox executable comes in two different flavors, i386 and AMD64. Can you verify that you installed the AMD64 version?

Comment: It has tried with both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a 64bit virtual machine. The bitness of the host OS is irrelevant, it's the VM that needs to be 64bit. From the [VBox website](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html) (emphasis mine):

### 64-bit guests

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
>   host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called “[Hardware vs. software virtualization](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)”).
> 2. You **must enable hardware virtualization** for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, **you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM**. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.
>
>    On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported
>      regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating
>      system in the guest.
>
> Warning
>
> On any host, you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that
>   you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for 64-bit
>   Windows VMs. See the section called “"[Advanced" tab](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-general-advanced)”. In addition, for
>   64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel
>   networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD
>   PCNet card; see the section called “Virtual networking hardware”.
>
> **If you use the "Create VM" wizard of the VirtualBox graphical user
>   interface (see the section called “Creating your first virtual
>   machine”), VirtualBox will automatically use the correct settings for
>   each selected 64-bit operating system type.**

So, just try creating a new Virtual Machine and make sure it's 64bit.

Comment: "The architecture of the host is irrelevant" ... "You need a 64-bit processor". Those 2 sentences contradict each other.

Comment: @Patrick the "You need a 64-bit processor" from the VM docs presumably refers to the VM's processor since the sentence just above it states "VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host [...]". As far as I can tell the architecture of the host _is_ irrelevant.

Comment: Afaik the 32 bit host must be on 64 bit hardware to host a 64 bit guest. So the architecture does matter (must be 64 bit) but the bitness of the host OS does not matter.

Comment: @casey ah, that may well be the case, I don't know. Thanks to both you and Patrick. I'll edit and clarify that it's the host OS that is irrelevant.

Comment: "You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM" - but where?

Comment: @blackcornail in the first screen of the create new VM wizard, choose "Other Linux (64-bit)". Any "64-bit" Linux will be fine probably.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I know of is if you don't have a 64-bit CPU. The host **OS** doesn't matter, and if hardware virtualisation is not enabled (vtx in BIOS settings) you can still create the VM but it will tell you what's wrong when you try to start it.